# PHP creating multimedia file on server

Tags: php, file, media

I receive multimedia file from JSON strings sent from devices.
If I store the string into a database and display in html afterwards then all is fine.

My problem is when there are 100's for files (pics,video,audio) then the code to build and display the files stored in the database takes far too long.

So I want to save the media files to the server and reference them instead. Maybe this will help on speed?

I'm having trouble saving correct media files thou .. The data is not viable in a file.

Incoming code for File creation:

```
$myfile = fopen("./Media/".$mFileName.$mFileExtension, "w") or die("ERROR");
$mMediaToWrite = base64_encode($mTheIncomingMediaData);
fwrite($myfile, $mMediaToWrite );
fclose($myfile);
```

Comment: I don't understand a single statement of your problem. Can you make it more clear please ? And what is the actual question ?

Comment: When I try view the file I have saved , I cannot open it